# Flutter Doctor on cmd

Tags: android-studio, flutter-doctor

I can not work on the Android Studio because there are some problem like this "Flutter (the doctor check crashed).

and then,
Due to an error, the doctor check did not complete. If the error message below is not helpful, please let us know about this issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues. Exception: Cannot find the executable for where . This can happen if the system32 folder (e.g. C: \Windows\System32 ) is removed from the PATH environment variable. Ensure that this is present and then try again after restarting the terminal and/or IDE.